# Nullspace and column space of invertible matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification

I want to show that the matrix $A$ $n\times n$ is invertible if and only if $N(A) = {0}$ and $C(A) = R^n$.

So far, this is what I've got:
Theorem: A is invertible $\implies N(A) = 0$ and $C(A) = 0$.
Proof:
1 - Solving $A \vec{x} = 0$:
$$ A^{-1}A\vec{x} = A^{-1}0$$
$$I_n\vec{x} = 0$$
$$\vec{x} = 0 \implies N(A) = 0$$

2 - Solving $A \vec{x} = \vec{b}$:
$$ A^{-1}A\vec{x} = A^{-1}\vec{b}$$
$$I_n\vec{x} = \vec{b}$$
$$\vec{x} = \vec{b} \implies C(A) = {\vec{x}} = {\rm I\!R}^n$$

That was the easy part. Now I can't do the other way around:

Theorem: $N(A) = 0$ and $C(A) = 0 \implies$ A is invertible.

Can anybody point me into the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: @Y.Fan I'm assuming column-space of $A$ which is the range of $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $N(A)=0$ and $C(A)=\Bbb R^n$, then for each $b\in\Bbb R^n$ $Ax=b$ has a unique solution. In particular, $Ax=0$ has a unique solution. Then, we do row reduction for $A$. Since $A$ has a unique solution, it won't have any "free variables". Hence, it has $n$ pivots. Therefore, $A$ is invertible.

Comment: thank you for your answer, Y. Fan. This is my first take on linear algebra, so I don't quite get what you mean by bijective map.

Comment: Y. Fan., I haven't seen determinants yet. But this is very helpful!

Comment: @mufernando So, what properties or theorems in linear algebra can you use to show the existence of the inverse?

Comment: We've been following Gilbert Strang's Linear Algebra and its Applications and we covered the first two chapters so far.
1 Matrices and Gaussian Elimination
1.1 Introduction
1.2 TheGeometryofLinearEquations
1.3 AnExampleofGaussianElimination 
1.4 MatrixNotationandMatrixMultiplication
1.5 TriangularFactorsandRowExchanges
1.6 InversesandTransposes
1.7 SpecialMatricesandApplications
2 Vector Spaces 77
2.1 VectorSpacesandSubspaces
2.2 SolvingAx=0andAx=b
2.3 LinearIndependence,Basis,andDimension
2.4 TheFourFundamentalSubspaces
2.5 GraphsandNetworks
2.6 LinearTransformations

Comment: @mufernando I've edited my answer. Hope this new one will help.

Comment: thanks! that was very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$ given by $T(x)=Ax$. Since the nullspace of $A$ is trivial and the column space is full we have that $T$ is injective and surjective respectively. Hence $T^{-1}$ the inverse map  of $T$ which is also a linear transformation exists that is $T(T^{-1}x)=x$ and $T^{-1}(Tx)=x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Since $T^{-1}$ is linear we have that $T^{-1}(x)=Bx$ for some $n$ by $n$ matrix $B$.

Because $T(T^{-1}x)=x$ and $T^{-1}(Tx)=x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$, we have that $ABx=BAx=x$ for all $x$. It follows that $AB=BA=I$ so that the inverse of $A$ exists as desired.

Comment: I haven't seen linear transformations yet so I don't get your solution, but thanks for your time.